# ASP.NET run exiftool

Tags: asp.net, executable

I am trying to run the exiftool.exe from ASP.NET and for the life of me I can't get it too run.  I am trying to run this [code](http://www.dreamincode.net/forums/topic/127657-extract-preview-image-from-raw-image-file-using-exiftool/)

For some reason in ASP.NET it is not executing.  Any and all help would be appreciated greatly!!

**UPDATED**

Here is my exact code I am trying to run:

```
    ProcessStartInfo ExifTool = new ProcessStartInfo();
    Process process = new Process();

    ExifTool.FileName = @"C:\Windows\exiftool.exe";
    ExifTool.Arguments = "-b -previewimage " + " " + filepath;
    ExifTool.UseShellExecute = false;
    ExifTool.RedirectStandardOutput = true;
    ExifTool.CreateNoWindow = true;
    ExifTool.RedirectStandardError = true;
    ExifTool.LoadUserProfile = true;

    process.StartInfo = ExifTool;
    process.Start();
```

Again there is no errors thrown, it's just not executing. Now if I run the file through command line and not the asp.net application it works just fine.

[image]

Comment: Ane exceptions would be great. What about permission to the webserver? That do you use?

Comment: it's not throwing any exceptions, it's just not running the executable file.  I am currently just running it on my local machine.

Comment: What happens when you debug though the code? What are the output from the `Process class`. There should be an Output Property or something alike to see whats maybe going on.

Comment: You says it dont run the commmand, but you are converting the Output to a Datetime which I guess should fail if there are no output. We need some more info on what you exactly are doing in your code.

Comment: I have edited my original post to show the code I am running.  Hope it helps.

Answer (score 1):

```
Dim ExifToolOutput As StreamReader = ExifTool.StandardOutput
```

Attached a debugger and see waht the `ExifToolOutput` contains ... it but be throwing some kind of command line error. Wrong parameters, path or something which do not show up as a .NET error.

### Updated

Since you are also using C#, here are something you can try:

```
ProcessStartInfo startInfo = new ProcessStartInfo();
Process process = new Process();

startInfo.FileName = @"ping";
startInfo.Arguments =  "-n 1 google.com";
startInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
startInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = true;
startInfo.CreateNoWindow = true;
startInfo.RedirectStandardError = true;
startInfo.LoadUserProfile = true;

process.StartInfo = startInfo;
process.Start();


var streamReader = process.StandardOutput as StreamReader;
var readToEnd = streamReader.ReadToEnd();
Console.WriteLine(readToEnd);
```

When I run this, I get the command command result printed out to the console, you should be able to do the same thing to a variable(via debugging) or if you have implemented some logging in your app.

Then you should be able to see what going on.

Comment: Tried what you advised and I am getting errors like System.NotSupportedException - Stream does not support seeking, System.InvalidoperationException - Timeouts are not supported on this stream.  Those are the only two errors I see but both 'CanSeek' and 'CanTimeout' is set to false by default.

Comment: Then you are using the Stream wrong. Try to copying all of the info. See my updated answer.

Comment: Since that fails. Try using my example above to read it out to a string, your own logging system or throw a Exception with the content from the `readToEnd`.

In your watch window you could also call `ReadToEnd()` on your stream.

Comment: The example above comes back with data but my example does not! dangit

Comment: That makes it more odd. You can also try to use the property `process.StandardError` but since errors should also be redirected, I dont think that will help. You can try just for fun, to specify a command that dont exist. Also a other command ... and please, do install that app in another place.

Comment: i have put the executable in the bin folder again and not in the windows folder since some users will not have access to the windows folder on external hosts.  still nothing.  i really do appreciate all your help Syska, really i do.

Comment: If you can run ping commands and others ... but not that program you installed I'm very sure its a permission issue. Do you use IISExpress, IIS or Casini? Do try to use some of the other web servers.

Answer (score 0):

Does your ASP.NET process AppPool running as Local Process? It needs rights to execute other files.

Comment: Trying to get him to post the Output from the Process. I'm also 99% sure its either a parameter or permission issue.

Comment: I've tried running the AppPool under local system and that still didn't work. Currently running under network service

Comment: But does that user/group have access to the path you are trying to read? The `windows` directory can be restricted.

Comment: I've tried the 'bin' folder, in the application directory itself and in the windows folder as instructed by the website itself to place it in the windows folder. still nothing.  i have tried impersonation as well and that didnt work either.  I have updated the original post showing an image of the errors i do get.

Comment: Can you try running this without redirecting Exif's output (let the Standard Output and Standard Error go to defaults)? I would guess you might need to specify additional info if you're re-directing output (destination maybe?).
Also, can you post stack trace? Actual Error message thrown?